# how can i make my JSON dynamically looks the same as in the example below for google charts?

Tags: php, json, for-loop, charts, google-visualization

First of all check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/hisham91/ws6mjkps/

---

```
CREATE TABLE  `googlecharts` (
 `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
 `item_code` VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL ,
 `sold_date` DATE NOT NULL ,
 `serial_no` INT NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;

INSERT INTO `googlecharts` VALUES (1, 'scratch card 3 USD', '2014-11-21', 22313);
INSERT INTO `googlecharts` VALUES (2, 'scratch card 10 USD', '2014-11-21', 90123);
INSERT INTO `googlecharts` VALUES (3, 'scratch card 4 USD', '2014-11-21', 47723);
INSERT INTO `googlecharts` VALUES (4, 'scratch card 3 USD', '2014-12-16', 22263);
INSERT INTO `googlecharts` VALUES (5, 'scratch card 10 USD', '2014-12-16', 11123);
INSERT INTO `googlecharts` VALUES (6, 'scratch card 4 USD', '2014-12-16', 45113);
INSERT INTO `googlecharts` VALUES (7, 'scratch card 3 USD', '2015-01-01', 23333);
INSERT INTO `googlecharts` VALUES (8, 'scratch card 10 USD', '2015-01-01', 34543);
INSERT INTO `googlecharts` VALUES (9, 'scratch card 4 USD', '2015-01-01', 41243);
INSERT INTO `googlecharts` VALUES (10, 'scratch card 3 USD', '2015-02-18', 23123);
INSERT INTO `googlecharts` VALUES (11, 'scratch card 10 USD', '2015-02-18', 34443);
INSERT INTO `googlecharts` VALUES (12, 'scratch card 4 USD', '2015-02-18', 45643);
INSERT INTO `googlecharts` VALUES (13, 'scratch card 3 USD', '2015-03-17', 23433);
INSERT INTO `googlecharts` VALUES (14, 'scratch card 10 USD', '2015-03-17', 34223);
INSERT INTO `googlecharts` VALUES (15, 'scratch card 4 USD', '2015-03-17', 45123);
```

---

Second of all I need to know how can I make my JSON data looks the same as this by knowing that the code below is for the database:

```
<?php

$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Problem while connecting to the database!");

mysql_select_db("charts", $con); 

$sth = mysql_query("SELECT item_code,serial_no,date FROM googlecharts group by item_code");
$rows = array();
$flag = true;

$table = array();

$table['cols'] = array(
//i guess i need a loop through the first column to get all items and make them labels
    array('label' => 'item code', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 'sum of serial numbers', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'sold month', 'type' => 'number')
);

$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $temp = array();

$temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['item_code']); 
$temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['serial_no']);
$temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['sold_date']);

$rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}

$table['rows'] = $rows;

$jsonTable = json_encode($table);

echo $jsonTable;
?>
```

---

by seeing the example in jsfiddle.net i think you will have an idea of what i'm trying to make please help me if you can.. i'm new here on stackoverflow and this is my first ***ordered*** question XD THANKS ALL for your time.
THUMBS UP !! **^_^**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dears I made this happen by something called "**pivot**" pivot-table or pivot-view Search over the internet ... if anyone wants to do this just tell me I will explain it to you. 
thanks all.